# Images sitemap not indexed

Tags: google-search-console, sitemap, images, xml-sitemap

For a website, I have uploaded two normal sitemaps and two image sitemaps (one for each language), respecting the structure given by Google.

While the normal sitemaps are indexed normally, only a few of the images are indexed, and I can't figure out what's wrong.

[image: Screenshot of GSC report]

Here is a simple record from the sitemap

```
<url>
    <loc>http://www.holypopstore.com/it/footwear-uomo/2304/nike-air-max-uptempo-95-as-qs</loc>
    <image:image>
        <image:loc>http://holypopdata.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/images/galleries/1646/922932-400.png</image:loc>
        <image:title>Air Max Uptempo 95 "All Star" university blue/white</image:title>
        <image:caption>922932-400</image:caption>
    </image:image>
</url>
```

Can anyone suggest what is wrong (in the map or in page)?

Answer (score 1):

Google is almost never willing to index all the pages and images available on a site.   The number of pages and images that get indexed is based on the site's reputation and the quality of the content.  Having half of your page indexed is quite normal.   Most of my sites have pages that are not indexed.

There are several reasons something might not be indexed:

- The reputation of the site is not high enough to get it indexed
- The content isn't linked from other pages on the site
- The content doesn't have any external inbound links
- The content isn't liked prominently enough from other pages on the site
- The URL is blocked from crawling
- The URL gave an error when Googlebot crawled it
- There is a soft error such as an error message on a 200 status page
- The content is too short
- The content appears to be spammy
- The content is a duplicate of some other URL
- The content is otherwise low quality.

Check to make sure that there aren't any obvious errors or quality problems, but I'll be the issue is lack of reputation.   As your site gets older and gains links and references, the number of indexed pages should grow.